# '_nextafter' not declared : CGAL in Qt Creator with Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, qt-creator, cgal

I've build CGAL like explained [here](http://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html).

Everything went well.

But now, I'm using Qt Creator with CGAL.

I've included the libraries in the .pro file :

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = TestCCGALAppliConsole
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG += c++11

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH  += /usr/local/include
LIBS        += -L/usr/local/include

macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgmp
macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lmpfr
macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lCGAL

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/build/lib/release/ -lCGAL-vc100-mt-gd-4.6
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/build/lib/debug/ -lCGAL-vc100-mt-4.6

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/build/lib/Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/build/lib/Debug

INCLUDEPATH += C:\local\CGAL-4.6\include

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/lib/ -llibgmp-10

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/include

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/lib/ -llibmpfr-4

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/CGAL-4.6/auxiliary/gmp/include


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0/ -lboost_system-vc100-mt-1_57
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0/ -lboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_57

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0/ -lboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_57
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0/ -lboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_57

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-10.0

INCLUDEPATH += C:\local\boost_1_57_0
```

and in my main.cpp I have :

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_items_with_id_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel         K;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3>     Polyhedron;
typedef Polyhedron::Vertex_iterator                                     Vertex_iterator;

int main() {

    Polyhedron mesh;
    std::ifstream input("inner.off");

    if ( !input || !(input >> mesh) || mesh.empty() )
    {
        //Debug
        std::cerr << "Not a valid off file." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for (Vertex_iterator v = mesh.vertices_begin() ; v!= mesh.vertices_end() ; ++v )
    {
        std::cout << v->point() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Hello You" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when I compile (with MinGW 4.9.1 32 bit with Qt 5.4.1) I'm having this error :

> C:\local\CGAL-4.6\include\CGAL\double.h:191: erreur : '_nextafter' was
>   not declared in this scope    return _nextafter(d1, d2); // works at
>   least for VC++-7.1

I can't figure out what's wrong...

Can you help me ?

**EDIT**

It seems that CGAL being compiled with Visual Studio C++ Compiler 10 involves that I have to compile with this compiler and not MinGW.

So I changed compile, I'm now using Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10 (amd64) in Qt Creator, but it still don't work. I have an error :

> impossible to open 'CGAL-vc100-mt-4.6.lib' file

Here's the complete error (sorry, french version...) :

```
 17:42:15: Exécution des étapes pour le projet TestCCGALAppliConsole...
 17:42:15: Configuration inchangée, étape qmake sautée.
 17:42:15: Débute : "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\TestCCGALAppliConsole" -I"." -I"\usr\local\include" -I"..\..\..\..\local\CGAL-4.6\build\lib\Debug" -I"..\..\..\..\local\CGAL-4.6\include" -I"..\..\..\..\local\CGAL-4.6\auxiliary\gmp\include" -I"..\..\..\..\local\CGAL-4.6\auxiliary\gmp\include" -I"..\..\..\..\local\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-10.0" -I"..\..\..\..\local\boost_1_57_0\lib64-msvc-10.0" -I"..\..\..\..\local\boost_1_57_0" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\qt-5.4.1-x64-msvc2010-rev1\qt-5.4.1-x64-msvc2010-rev1\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\qt-5.4.1-x64-msvc2010-rev1\qt-5.4.1-x64-msvc2010-rev1\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\qt-5.4.1-x64-msvc2010-rev1\qt-5.4.1-x64-msvc2010-rev1\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Raphael\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.1988.32.jom
 main.cpp
echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "debug\\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe.embed.manifest">debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe_manifest.rc
if not exist debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe if exist debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe.embed.manifest del debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe.embed.manifest
if exist debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe.embed.manifest debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe_manifest.bak
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe @C:\Users\Raphael\AppData\Local\Temp\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe.1988.5000.jom
 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'CGAL-vc100-mt-4.6.lib'
 jom: C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\build-TestCCGALAppliConsole-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MSVC2010_x64-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\TestCCGALAppliConsole.exe] Error 1104
 jom: C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\build-TestCCGALAppliConsole-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MSVC2010_x64-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
 17:42:21: Le processus "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 2.
 Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet TestCCGALAppliConsole (kit : Desktop Qt 5.4.1 MSVC2010 x64)
 When executing step "Make"
 17:42:21: Temps écoulé : 00:05.
```

Comment: https://github.com/insieme/insieme/blob/b667eb6aa6bfd6feb56e646afef160ad6a886925/test/cpp/cgal/tests/CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER/CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER.cpp#L24-L27

Comment: Does mingw provide the `nextafter` functionality under any name? `__builtin_nextafter` is the one that comes to mind, but I am not even sure it would work.

Comment: How did you build CGAL **exactly**? Was -std=c++11 involved at any point? That would explain it (you want -std=gnu++11 instead).

Comment: Wait, the instructions you are linking are for compiling CGAL with Visual Studio, and now you expect to use the result with mingw? That doesn't make sense...

Comment: I'm now using Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10.0 (amd64) but it still don't work : _impossible to open 'CGAL-vc100-mt-4.6.lib' file_ while with mingw the library was open...

Comment: With mingw your code didn't compile, so the linker was never involved and the library was not "open". Do you actually have a file with exactly that name? (check every character) Was the error message really that short?

Comment: The file have exactly that name, the librarie were included in the .pro file with right clik and "Add a library" so the path is good also.
My question was **edited** with the full error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's right there in your message:

> when I compile (with MinGW

versus

> works at least for VC++-7.1

`_nextafter` is a Microsoft extension used by CGAL. MinGW doesn't appear to support it.

Comment: It means that I've got to compile with the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler in Qt Creator ?

Comment: Actually, the whole CGAL project has never been tested with MinGW, and it seems that there does be some compilation errors.